# Make buttons adapt to window resizing (re-position) in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, resize, scenebuilder

I'm still learning about JavaFX, and one of my biggest frustrations is that I can't figure out how to reposition my buttons (or any other element) when I resize the window. Let's say my width is 500px and I have a button at 250px. Now I'm resizing the window to 1500px. The button stays where it was before, however I want it to be at 750 px now since that's half the length.

This is what it looks like:

[image: first picture]

And this is after I changed the window size to fullscreen mode, and as you can see on my awful drawing, I want the buttons to move as well, but to the "new" middle.

[image: second picture]
I'm really not sure how to handle this resizing problem, so I hope you guys can help me.

Thanks in advance!

> FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="1080.0" maxWidth="1920.0" minHeight="720.0" minWidth="1080.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <center>
      <MediaView fx:id="mediaV" fitHeight="200.0" fitWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
   <bottom>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #1C1C1C;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="albumCoverView" fitHeight="204.0" fitWidth="222.0" layoutX="-1.0" layoutY="-2.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
            <HBox fx:id="hBoxButtons" layoutX="447.0" layoutY="75.0" prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="256.0">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="previousButton" focusTraversable="false" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlePlay" prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="64.0" style="-fx-background-image: url(&quot;sample/buttons/previous.png&quot;); -fx-background-size: 64px 64px; -fx-background-color: #1C1C1C;" />
                  <Button fx:id="playPauseButton" focusTraversable="false" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlePlay" prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="64.0" style="-fx-background-image: url(&quot;sample/buttons/play.png&quot;); -fx-background-size: 64px 64px; -fx-background-color: #1C1C1C;" />
                  <Button fx:id="nextButton" focusTraversable="false" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlePlay" prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="64.0" style="-fx-background-image: url(&quot;sample/buttons/next.png&quot;); -fx-background-size: 64px 64px; -fx-background-color: #1C1C1C;" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <Button fx:id="stopButton" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="374.0" layoutY="76.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleStop" prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="64.0" style="-fx-background-image: url(&quot;sample/buttons/stop.png&quot;); -fx-background-size: 64px 64px; -fx-background-color: #1C1C1C;" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </bottom>
   <left>
      <Pane prefHeight="520.0" prefWidth="268.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2E2E2E;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <TextField layoutX="25.0" layoutY="36.0" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="220.0" promptText="Search" style="-fx-border-radius: 50; -fx-background-radius: 50;" />
         </children></Pane>
   </left>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Look at some tutorials on JavaFX layouts.  Also, you would need to provide your code (a [mcve]) for us to help with this issue.

Comment: I don’t really have that much code. This is just designed in scene builder and run afterwards

Comment: Post your FXML.

Comment: What you designed in SceneBuilder is important, and so is your code. How can you expect us to help you fix your code without showing us your code? We know what's important :)

Comment: No idea how those other nodes are supposed to be positioned relative to each other or what nodes there are. Using the right parent with the right parameters will fix your problem. What kind of scene structure you need to use depends on the scene you're trying to create & the desired behavour on resizing.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kEieMPWV

Answer (score 0):

I believe your use of `BorderPane` as a root node is correct in this situation, but I personally don't like to use `BorderPane`. My solution uses `VBox` as the root node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.MediaView?>

<VBox maxHeight="1080.0" maxWidth="1920.0" minHeight="720.0" minWidth="1080.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <HBox VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <VBox maxWidth="476.0" prefHeight="520.0" prefWidth="268.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2E2E2E;" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <TextField prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="220.0" promptText="Search" style="-fx-border-radius: 50; -fx-background-radius: 50;">
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="20.0" right="20.0" top="40.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
               </children>
            </VBox>
            <StackPane maxWidth="1444.0" prefHeight="520.0" prefWidth="812.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <MediaView fx:id="mediaV" fitHeight="200.0" fitWidth="200.0" />
               </children>
            </StackPane>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox prefHeight="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #1C1C1C;">
         <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="albumCoverView" fitHeight="204.0" fitWidth="222.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
            <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <HBox fx:id="hBoxButtons" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" spacing="1.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button fx:id="stopButton" focusTraversable="false" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleStop" prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="64.0" style="-fx-background-image: url(&quot;sample/buttons/stop.png&quot;); -fx-background-size: 64px 64px;">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets right="10.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="previousButton" focusTraversable="false" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlePlay" prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="64.0" style="-fx-background-image: url(&quot;sample/buttons/previous.png&quot;); -fx-background-size: 64px 64px;" />
                        <Button fx:id="playPauseButton" focusTraversable="false" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlePlay" prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="64.0" style="-fx-background-image: url(&quot;sample/buttons/play.png&quot;); -fx-background-size: 64px 64px;" />
                        <Button fx:id="nextButton" focusTraversable="false" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlePlay" prefHeight="64.0" prefWidth="64.0" style="-fx-background-image: url(&quot;sample/buttons/next.png&quot;); -fx-background-size: 64px 64px;" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
            </StackPane>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```